# How long does concrete dust take to settle

Tags: concrete, painting, plaster, dust

I'm getting some wiring done and having the electrician chase the new wires.
The walls are concrete so I know that this is going to make a huge mess and need serious work after the electrical stuff is done.

But one guy I spoke to said to remember that the Concrete Dust would take a while to settle after the work.

This leads into several questions:

1. Just how long will it take?
2. Are the any ways to speed it up? (Walking round repeatedly with a bunch of big mister bottles to wet the air and pull the dust down?)
3. Does concrete dust in the air affect the plastering? If so, how long should I leave between the two sets of work?
4. The concrete dust will surely affect the repainting we'll be doing after the making good. How long should I leave between the concrete work being finished and the painting starting?

Comment: Please clarify "sparky". Would I be correct in guessing an electrician?

Comment: @ojait correct. Replaced

Answer (score 1):

Concrete dust becomes air-bourn when it is pulverized (due to tool use: drilling, sawing, hammering, etc.). The fine silt concrete dust is thrown into the surrounding air by electric tool motor fans or other air currents. The particulate is so small and light-weight any slight breeze will distribute it until it finally sinks and lands on a surface.

Where, when, and how long will depend on too many extenuating circumstances to even guess at. The best way to deal with any dust becoming air-born is to stop it before it happens. I've found a shop-vac held just above the concrete surface that is being worked on does a smashing right good job at eliminating dust.